# How to run a Digital clock on windows phone 8 Tile?(Description inside)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm working on setting the Tiles for the windows phone 8 apps, would somebody tell me how to update the tile time for every minute like the first time tile in the picture below,

[image]

I've done using `ScheduledAgent` but that works fine when I start the service in debug mode. . .

I've seen an example in [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff) but that one is for metro app. . .

somebody please tell me how to achieve this in windows phone 8. . .

Comment: maybe have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/481059/DigiClockPlus

Comment: I too tried a lot on this topic but never get one solution. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the livetile more than every 30 minutes on Windows Phone unless you push out a push notification from a server every minute which wouldn't be very efficient anyway.

Comment: But Microsoft had done it already, so I thought there might be a way to achieve it. . . Anyway thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hi Robert, this is known fact! Nokia, HTC and Samsung does it; why cant other developers have this?

Comment: The OEM:s doesn't have the same SDK as normal developers have. An example is that Samsung has written an app/system setting the can block incoming phonecalls which is impossible to do as a normal 3rd party developer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something with Background Executable task 
but in order to do that you need to declare location capability which will scare people off
you could get close to the functionality using a scheduled task ( there is a preview of the windows phone 8 internals book that covers it loosely I think but from memory I believe the caveat is that you get approximately 25 seconds execution time per 30 minutes so updating  the tile using  this methods should be ok for per minute accuracy (almost)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand, can you explain briefly about this with some reference. . .